# Using a variable with Substr in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, types, triggers, substr

I am trying to use a variable to set the length of a substr command.
If I explicitly set say 0,13 the code works fine however, I want to be able to use a variable.

Near the end of the code is the area of question:

:new.DOCNO := substr(:new.DESCRIP,0,15); -- success ... but limited

:new.DOCNO := substr(:new.DESCRIP,0,n_len); -- fail

The code overall is looking to find a number pattern from a file name and place it into another column.

Example: HR_1000-0001_A This is a file.pdf

I have tried various data types: integer, number,... etc.
The code compiles but fails when I run the trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER set_doc_number
BEFORE UPDATE ON external_doc
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (
    new.STATUS = 'Released'
    -- current document# is either '' or is ONLY a number
    AND (
            new.DOC_LIBRARY_ID = ''
            OR              
            REGEXP_LIKE(new.DOC_LIBRARY_ID,'(\d+)')
        )
    )
DECLARE 
    -- init variables
    b_update boolean;
    n_len number := 0;
BEGIN
    -- reset for each loop
    b_update := FALSE;

    -- check if criteria is met 

    -- AAA_####-####_AA
    IF b_update = FALSE AND REGEXP_LIKE(:new.DESCRIP,'([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]_(\d{4})-(\d{4})_[A-Z])') THEN 
        b_update := TRUE;
        n_len := 15;
    END IF;
    -- AA_####-####_AA
    IF b_update = FALSE AND REGEXP_LIKE(:new.DESCRIP,'([A-Z][A-Z]_(\d{4})-(\d{4})_[A-Z])') THEN 
        b_update := TRUE;
        n_len := 14;
    END IF;
    -- AAA_####-####_A
    IF b_update = FALSE AND REGEXP_LIKE(:new.DESCRIP,'([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]_(\d{4})-(\d{4})_[A-Z])') THEN 
        b_update := TRUE;
        n_len := 15;
    END IF;
    -- AA_####-####_A
    IF b_update = FALSE AND REGEXP_LIKE(:new.DESCRIP,'([A-Z][A-Z]_(\d{4})-(\d{4})_[A-Z])') THEN 
        b_update := TRUE;
        n_len := 14;
    END IF;
    -- AAA_####-####
    IF b_update = FALSE AND REGEXP_LIKE(:new.DESCRIP,'([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]_(\d{4})-(\d{4}))') THEN  
        b_update := TRUE;
        n_len := 13;
    END IF;
    -- AA_####-####
    IF b_update = FALSE AND REGEXP_LIKE(:new.DESCRIP,'([A-Z][A-Z]_(\d{4})-(\d{4}))') THEN       
        b_update := TRUE;
        n_len := 12;
    END IF;

    -- can we update?
    IF b_update = TRUE THEN
        -- update
        :new.DOCNO := substr(:new.DESCRIP,0,n_len);
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: When it fails, are you getting an error message? Or does it just not update as expected?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why using `n_len` fails, it looks fine to me. PL/SQL indexes start at 1 and not 0, but it works fine if you use 0, so that's not an issue.

If you're going to use regexp functions, I'd suggest just using `regexp_substr`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER set_doc_number
BEFORE UPDATE ON external_doc
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (
    new.STATUS = 'Released'
    -- current document# is either '' or is ONLY a number
    AND (
            new.DOC_LIBRARY_ID = ''
            OR              
            REGEXP_LIKE(new.DOC_LIBRARY_ID,'(\d+)')
        )
    )
DECLARE 
    -- init variables
    v_docno varchar2(20);
BEGIN
    -- look for a str with (2-3 alpha)_####-####(optional underscore and 1-3 alpha)
    v_docno := regexp_substr(:new.DESCRIP,'[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]?_\d{4}-\d{4}(_[A-Z][A-Z]?[A-Z]?)?');

    -- can we update?
    IF v_docno is not null THEN
        -- update
        :new.DOCNO := v_docno;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: After breaking down the error line by line it's the only place initially that appeared to fail. Now it's failing even when I comment out the update area so, I suspect it's something else or maybe it's something elsewhere in the system I am working on. Thanks for the response. I will experiment further and incorporate your suggestions.